# Content Builder Approvals

Tags: marketing-cloud, approval-process, content-builder

I would like some informations about Approvals.

The questions is:

1. Could I send an email to a testable data extension without having previously approved it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The send option is not available for messages that have not completed the approval process when approvals are enabled.

[image]

[image]

To send to a Test DE, you would need to go to the Preview & Test tab in a message and select the Test Send option on the left rail. From there you can select a Test DE.

[image]

Comment: I have an update: I have tried to test and i have noticed the following aspect: without Approvals, clicking on Preview and Test > Test Data Extension on the left icon "Test Send"> it's possible to send test email

Comment: You're absolutely right! I forgot about this. I'll edit my response to include that!